# Displaying foreign key in jtable strange

Tags: sql, netbeans, jtable, foreign-keys

Whenever I have a table with a foreign key associated , when displaying the rows in a jtable , the value of the foreign key is being shown like this.It is not wrong but I would like for it to be shown like a normal value. Any ideas?

[image]

[image: pic]

Comment: *foreign key is being shown like this..* like what exactly?

Comment: I didn't put the links, sorry

Comment: Show us your Java code displaying the data

Comment: I didn't really write a code ,I used the 'bind elements ' option of the table and imported data from the database